# Changing \parts in exam document class

Tags: exam

I am using \parts in the document class exam. I have noticed that it will always start the lettering with "a". Is there a way to change this in latex? I have already tried using the following:

```
\setcounter{part}{2}
```

I was wondering if there is any way that I could start lettering with "b" or "c".

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  Please **always** provide a MWE (Minimal Working Example), which presents your problem in a compilable code.  IN your case, setting the counter part to 2 will only result in starting the next part after this command with value 3.  If you want to change the numbering system, you have to use something like `\arabic{\thecounter}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had the right idea, but the counter you want to change is `partno` not `part`.

Code:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question
What if there were no air?
\begin{parts}

\setcounter{partno}{1}

\part[5]
Describe the effect on the balloon industry.
\part[5]
Describe the effect on the aircraft industry.
\end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Yields:

[image]